# What is the difference between social choice function and social welfare function?

Tags: functions, voting-theory

I am trying to understand a shard proof on Arrow's Impossibility Theorem and Gibbard-Satterthwaite Theorem.

I stumbled upon these 2 different functions, and I cannot understand the difference between them:

```
f:L^n→A - social choice function

F:L^n->L* - social welfare function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that finite set of alternatives are a,b and c.

A social choice function can have one single output which can be a or b or c.

A social welfare function can have any ranking as output such as $a<b<c$.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly your setting is as follows:

- List item A set of alternatives $A$, with $\mathcal{L}$ the set of orderings over $A$.
- List item A finite set $N$ of individuals with cardinality $n$.
- List item Each individual has a preference relation $L\in \mathcal{L}$.
- List item A preference profile is a list of preferences relation for each individuals in the population $L^n \in \mathcal{L}^n$.

Then a social choice function associates every profile in your domain with an alternative, that is it picks a chosen alternative in $A$ for every profile of preferences.

A social welfare function on the other hand associates every profile of preferences with a complete ranking of the alternatives -- not only with the best alternative in $A$.

Beware that when social welfare functions associate ordering profiles with a (social) ordering of the alternatives, people tend to call these functions social *ordering* functions. It may be clearer to limit the use of the term social *welfare* function to function associating social welfare levels to vectors of *utilities*. These two may be viewed as equivalent only when the ordering can be represented by a utility function (e.g. when the ordering is continuous).